# elemMatch query does not work in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

This mongodb query works correctly returning documents with matching sub-document criteria

```
db.user.find(
    {Type: {"$in": ["local","google"]}, 
     Alerts:{$elemMatch:{"Frequency.Type":"daily","IsActive":true}}
})
```

When I convert this into a php array it returns nothing

```
$qry = array("Type"=>array('$in'=>array("local","google")),
       array('Alerts'=>array('$elemMatch'=>array('Frequency.Type'=>'daily','IsActive'=>true))));
```

This is structure of document

```
{
    "Email" : "someemail@domain.com",
    "Type" : "confirmed",
    "FName" : "Sung",

    "Alerts" : [ 
        {
            "Keyword" : "administrative",
            "Frequency" : {
                "Type" : "weekly"
            }
            "IsActive" : true
        },
        {
            "Keyword" : "marketing",
            "Frequency" : {
                "Type" : "daily"
            }
            "IsActive" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I take the elemMatch portion out of the php array it returns rows. So I am connecting and there is data there. Not sure if I coded the array right but I think $elemMatch not supported correctly in php mongodb library. Aggregation is not an option. I need a cursor since this will return large dataset and dont want to crash the server. Searched the web and cannot find a working example of $elemMatch mongodb query done in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had one too many arrays.

```
$qry = array(
    "Type"=>array('$in'=>array("local","google")),
    "Alerts"=>array('$elemMatch'=>array(
        "Frequency.Type"=> "daily",'IsActive'=>true
    ))
);
```

In the future, try to indent your code as I have done so you can clearly see the structure.
Also since you are comparing to a known JSON structure, do this:

```
echo json_encode( $qry, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) ."\n";
```

And then you can clearly see what you have done that does not match the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

BTW - if you have a query in JSON format that you know works and you just want to get it into PHP, you can use PHP's `json_decode` and `var_export` to covert your (valid) JSON query to a PHP query.

For example, your query above (after JSONifying a bit) could be converted using this code:

```
var_export(json_decode(
    '{
       "Type": {"$in": ["local","google"]}, 
       "Alerts":{ "$elemMatch": {"Frequency.Type":"daily","IsActive":true}}
     }',true));
```

And the output (after removing some white spaces, because the output of `var_export` is lousy with white spaces) looks like this:

```
array (
  'Type' => array ( '$in' => array ( 0 => 'local', 1 => 'google', ), ),
  'Alerts' => array ( '$elemMatch' => array (
    'Frequency.Type' => 'daily',
    'IsActive' => true,
  ), ),
)
```

(you'd probably also want to remove numbered indexes).

Answer (score 0):

I having pretty similar issue.
Document structure:

```
[
   {
      "locale":"en",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"enValue"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "locale":"ru",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"ruValue"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Code:

```
/** @var BSONDocument|null $result  */
$result = $collection->findOne(
    [
        'locale' => ['$eq' => $locale],
         'translations' => ['$elemMatch' => ['name' => 'translation1']]
    ]
);
dd(json_encode($result->getArrayCopy()));
```

the json encoded result is:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e988dda2566154a5a442a53"
    },
    "locale": "en",
    "translations": [
        {
            "name": "translation1",
            "value": "translation222 value for en"
        },
        {
            "name": "translation2",
            "value": "translation222 value for en"
        },
        {
            "name": "translation3",
            "value": "translation 333 value for en"
        }
    ]
}
```